# Scaling data for neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I was using a sequential model in keras for categorical classification.

given data:

```
x_train = np.random.random((5000, 20))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(5000, 1)), num_classes=10)
x_test = np.random.random((500, 20))
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(500, 1)), num_classes=10)
```

feature scaling is important:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(x_train) 
x_train = scaler.transform(x_train) 
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)
```

model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=20))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))    

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=100,
          batch_size=32)
```

data to be predicted

```
z = np.random.random((9999000, 20))
```

Should I scale this data?
How to scale this data?

```
predictions = model.predict_classes(z)
```

As you see that, the training and testing samples are only a few as compared to the data to be predicted (`z`). Using the scaler fitted with `x_train` to rescale `x_test`, seems OK.
However, using the same scaler fitted with only 5000 samples to rescale `z` (9999000 samples), seems not OK. Are there any best practices in the field of deep learning to solve this problem?

For classifiers not sensitive to feature scaling linke Random Forests do not have this issue. However, for deep learning, this issue exists.

The training data shown here is for example purpose only. In the real problem, the training data is not coming from the same (uniform) probability distribution. It is difficult to label data and the training data has human bias towards easy to label. Only the samples easier to label was labelled.

Comment: S/O is for _concise, answerable_ questions. What answer are you hoping to get? Having labeled data is of course more difficult than unlabeled data. Some people use semi-labeled data, and label data artificially, based on distance metrics to the labeled data. But this is more a discussion than answer. It's an ongoing field of research.

Comment: @NicolasGervais question seems to be about the very *practical* problem of how you scale new data for NNs after fitting the model; not sure why you seem to think it is about unlabeled data, semi-labeled ones, distance metrics, or open research topics.

Comment: No it's not. You should review what's considered off-topic because that's a perfect example of virtually every reason to close a question.

Comment: @NicolasGervais That's another story; you have a point voting to close the question as off-topic (it is probably a better fit for Cross Validated or Data Science SE, since it is about methodology and not programming), which I am not criticizing. That, however, does not make your comment correct - it *is* a practical question and not a research topic.

Comment: @NicolasGervais plus, you have not actually voted to close as off-topic, but as "Needs more focus". Code and reproducible example are here, so not a correct reason for closure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, using the same scaler fitted with only 5000 samples to rescale `z` (9999000 samples), seems not OK.

Not clear why you think so. This is exactly the standard practice, i.e. using the scaler fitted with your training data, as you have correctly done with your test data:

```
z_scaled = scaler.transform(z) 
predictions = model.predict_classes(z_scaled)
```

The number of samples (500 or 10^6) does not make any difference here; the important thing is for all this data (`x` and `z`) to come from the same probability distribution. In practice (and for data that may still be in the future) this is only *assumed* (and one of the things to watch for after model deployment is exactly if this assumption does not hold, or ceases to be correct after some time). But especially here, with your simulated data coming from the exact same (uniform) probability distribution, this is exactly the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration to answer my post. Actually, in my real case, training data is not coming from the same (uniform) probability distribution (Edit 1).

Comment: @tbs Obviously, this (i.e simulated data, as here) cannot happen in the real world of course, but it does not change the argument of the answer; almost all ML practice implicitly uses the hypothesis that the data (train, test, future) are coming from the same probability distribution, otherwise the whole orifice cannot really stand (for an exception, see "concept drift").